# The quickest way to calculate a user's average speed?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I'm using Location Manager and trying to calculate the user's average speed for the last 60 seconds.

I get user's speed from the Location Manager every second, when `didUpdateLocations` is called. I then append that speed to an array.

My plan is to calculate the average speed from this array of speeds recorded in `didUpdateLocations`.

However, at the start, the array is empty. Although it gets populated every second, I will still want to calculate the average speed, even though the array doesn't have 60 speeds yet. In this case, I would have to only use the values recorded, for example, after 5 seconds and 5 speeds, the average speed would be calculated using those values. After time, the array gets populated, and the appending of the newest speed values makes the oldest ones get removed from the array.

Is there easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Your current explanation sounds correct. You can still get average speeds without having the array being full yet. You might setup your speed array like so:

```
let max = 60
var speeds = Array<Float>()
```

Then, every time the `didUpdateLocations` method is called, you can add the user's speed to this `speeds` array. However, since you don't want the array to be longer than 60 items, you can set a max and remove older speeds to keep the length at 60. You might implement this like so:

```
// In didUpdateLocations():    

if speeds.count == max {
    speeds.remove(at: 0)
}

speeds.append(newSpeed)
```

Then, to calculate their average speed, just take the items from the speeds array and average them by dividing their sum by their count.

```
var total: Float = 0.0
speeds.forEach { speed in
    total += speed
}

var averageSpeed = total / Float(speeds.count)
print(averageSpeed)
```

Comment: The declaration `var speeds = Array<Float>()` breaks something in my other class  
  
`for location in locations {
            minLat = min(minLat, location.latitude)
            minLng = min(minLng, location.longitude)
            maxLat = max(maxLat, location.latitude)
            maxLng = max(maxLng, location.longitude)`  
the last two lines giving an error: "Cannot call value of non-function type 'int'

Comment: @user2265192 You probably have a function called `max`. Change your `max` variable to be called something else, like `maxSpeed`.